# Finite length $A$-algebras are finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a field and $M$ a module over a (associative, unital) finite-dimensional $k$-algebra $A$.
The length of $M$ is the unique length of a composition series for $M$.
How does $M$ having finite length imply that $M$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module?

I know that there are similar statements for modules over artinian rings (and that finite-dimensional algebras are artinian rings etc.) but I can't at the moment see how to show this directly even though I've been told it's apparently easy.

Comment: Hint: Pick a non-zero element, quotient out the submodule generated by it. Now do induction on the length.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I've been trying, I'll give it another shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0 = M_0 \subsetneq M_1 \subsetneq \dotsb \subsetneq M_t = M$ be a composition series for $M$, so every factor $M_i / M_{i-1},\ 1 \leq i \leq t$ is simple and so $M_{i-1}$ is maximal in $M_i$.

For every $1 \leq i \leq t$ choose $x_i \in M_i \setminus M_{i-1}$, then $M_i$ is the module generated by $M_{i-1} \cup \{x_i\}$, which is also the module generated by $X_{i-1} \cup \{x_i\}$ where $X_{i-1}$ is a generating set for $M_{i-1}$ ($0$ is generated by the empty set).
By induction $X_t =  \{x_1, \dotsc, x_t\}$ generates $M_t = M$, so in particular $M$ has a generating set of cardinality $l(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Firstly remark that having length $1$ implies the module is finitely generated. Since it is an irreducible module over an associative algebra.

Suppose the result true for length $n$ module, let $M$ a module of length $n+1$,$N_0\subset N_1...\subset N_n\subset M$ a composition sequence of length $n+1$,shows that the length of $N_n$ is $n$ and the length of $M/N_n$ is 1. Conclude recursively.

Answer (score 1):

A module of finite length is noetherian, so it is finitely generated.

Comment: Much appreciated Mariano (though I was looking for a direct proof).

Comment: Well, one usually defines «finite length» to mean «artinian and noetherian», so this is quite direct :-)